# Compare localeTimeString in array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm checking whether the current time  falls between the array of times. The result that is expected is to return the first time that is closer to the current time.

```js
const dateTimes = [{
    value: '3:00:00 PM'
  },
  {
    value: '4:00:00 PM'
  },
  {
    value: '5:00:00 PM'
  }
]

const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

const result = dateTimes.find(({
  value
}) => currentTime > value)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your dateTimes array contains one object with three identical property names.  I think you meant to have three different objects.

Comment: You are right, I have edited my question @James

Answer (score 0):

This approach take the absolute difference between current time and object time.

```js
const dateTimes = [
      {value: '3:00:00 PM'},
      {value: '4:00:00 PM'},
      {value: '5:00:00 PM'}
    ];

let currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
let currentHour = parseInt(currentTime.split(":")[0]);
let currentMinutes = parseInt(currentTime.split(":")[1]);
let currentSeconds = parseInt(currentTime.split(":")[2]);

let dif = -1, closest = "";
dateTimes.forEach(function (e){
  let hour = parseInt(e.value.split(":")[0]);
  let minutes = parseInt(e.value.split(":")[1]);
  let seconds = parseInt(e.value.split(":")[2].split(" ")[0]);
  let stamp = e.value.split(":")[2].split(" ")[1];
  
  hour = stamp == "PM" ? hour + 12 : hour;
  let thisDif = Math.abs(hour * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds - (currentHour * 3600 + currentMinutes * 60 + currentSeconds));
  
  if (dif < 0 || thisDif < dif) {
    dif = thisDif;
    closest = e.value;
  }
});

console.log(closest);
```